# Adempiere - Web UI Debugging 380Version

Tags: web, jboss, adempiere

I have been successfully able to debug 360 370 version using Tomcat Server , but the Source Code of 380 Version doesn't works in similar way, When I follow the same steps it gives me error , Can anyone refer me the correct source code which enables Web UI debugging.

I know all the steps once I get the right source, Can anyone guide me???
Has anyone been able to do this successfully???

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: why are you still using adempiere?
you should start using idempiere, the next generation of adempiere; with osgi.
for more info on dev go here:
http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Install_Development_Prerequisites

Comment: we have tested idempiere also, but it lacks in features, although osgi framework is a big plus, but functionality wise,Manufacturing it is not that good as Adempiere so decided to stick to Adempiere 380.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps to enable the Web UI on ADempiere

1. Open Adempiere\jboss\bin\run.bat
2. There is a command "rem set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y %JAVA_OPTS%"
3. delete "rem" from the code , So server will listen to the port 8787
4. open eclipse -> Debug Configuration -> Remote Java Application , Then, create a new configuraion, 
   Give the configuration name : 'AdempiereWeb'(anything)
   Give the Project Name, 
   Connection Type : Standard(Socket Attach)
   Host : localhost
   Port : 8787
5. Run Adempiere370\utils\RUN_Server2.bat
   It will start and waiting to the response from the port 8787.
6. Debug the 'AdempiereWeb' configuration

7 set the debug break points on the class, It will detect the break points ; DONE

You can see this link, where its explained the webui debug.
http://tekadempiere.blogspot.com/2013/12/to-debug-adempiere-web.html

Answer (score 0):

you can debug the adempiere-380 as steps described as here
http://wiki.adempiere.net/Creating_WebUI_Workspace_using_Eclipse_Webtool

I am using java JDK(7), Eclipse(mars), and tomcat(8) on windows 7. it works flawlessly

for adempiere zk customization use the following thread
http://www.adempiere.net/forums#!/thread/43968/44220